# Uso do nextLine() em java

Tags: java

Olá comecei a estudar java a pouco tem e me deparei com um problema :

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class MainD {    
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);      
            int i = scan.nextInt();
            
            if(i == 1) {
                System.out.println("string a");
                String a = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("string b");
                String b = scan.nextLine();
            }
    }
}
```

conselo ao executar.

```
1
Digite a string a
Digite a string b
```

Ao executar este codigo ele acaba executando as quatro linhas parando somente no ultimo nextLine(), o next() resoveria isto mas só adiciona uma palavra, alguem poderia me explicar o porque, desde ja agradeço.
ps estou estudando programacao a apenao 3 semanas.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que o `nextInt()` não consome o caractere de quebra de linha `\n`, então a chamada subsequente de `nextLine()` o consome, fazendo com que o programa pule para a leitura da string b.

Você precisa consumir o line break `\n` antes de ler a string a.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainD {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);      
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        
        if(i == 1) {
            scan.nextLine(); // Essa linha faz com que o `\n` que restou do input numérico seja consumido.
            System.out.println("string a");
            String a = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("string b");
            String b = scan.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```